# Can I create a custom unique id in SQL Server without the possibility of duplicating it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to generate Ticket ID's which have the following format:

```
TicketType+YYMMDD+nnnn
```

- TicketType is 4-characters
- YYMMDD is 2-digit year/month/day
- nnnn is a 4-digit incrementing number starting at 0001 for each TicketType+YYMMDD

I have something that's been working for a year, but today revealed a flaw.

```
DECLARE @TktType varchar(4) = CASE @TypeId WHEN 1 THEN 'TKTT' WHEN 2 THEN 'TKTD' WHEN 3 THEN 'TKTV' WHEN 4 THEN 'TKTB' END

DECLARE @DatePart varchar(6) = CAST(YEAR(GetDate()) - 2000 AS varchar(4)) + 
                               RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(GetDate()) AS varchar(2)), 2) + 
                               RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY(GetDate()) AS varchar(2)), 2)

DECLARE @nextNum varchar(4) = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, MAX(SUBSTRING(SO, 11, 4))) + 1 FROM T_SO WHERE SO LIKE @TktType + @DatePart +'%')

SET @nextNum = RIGHT('000' + COALESCE(@nextNum, '1'), 4)

INSERT INTO tblTickets (TktID, ...)
VALUES (@TktType + @DatePart + @nextNum, ...)
```

This has been working for a year without a hitch. Can you guess what happened?  Today two people hit it at the same time. Both generated the same Ticket ID, and since the TktID column is the primary key, one of them got a nice "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint" message.

So i've thought about creating a new table for each ticket type with an identity column and a bit column. Insert a 0 and get back the inserted id. This would mean having to truncate the table and reset the identity seed every midnight. I'm sure there are unforeseen issues with this.

I've also thought about looping and incrementing the number until the insert is successfull. Bad.

And one of my peers suggested using a transaction to lock the table which would make anyone else wait until I was done. Not sure about this.

Has anyone else had to do something similar? I'm looking for suggestions and advice on how to best resolve the issue.

EDIT: I think I have something that works. Feel free to leave your thoughts.

First, I created a table that has a row for each ticket type:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_TicketID](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TicketType] [varchar](4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL
)
```

Then I created a procedure that accepts a ticket type and returns a full Ticket ID:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_CreateTicketID
    @TicketType varchar(4),
    @TicketID varchar(14) OUTPUT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Date DATE = GETDATE()
DECLARE @out TABLE (TicketID varchar(14))

UPDATE T_TicketID
SET 
    id = CASE WHEN [Date] =  @Date THEN id + 1 ELSE 1 END,
    [Date] = CASE WHEN [Date] = @Date THEN [Date] ELSE @Date END
OUTPUT @TicketType + 
       CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(@Date) - 2000) + 
       RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar, MONTH(@Date)), 2) + 
       RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar, DAY(@Date)), 2) + 
       RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar, INSERTED.id), 4) 
INTO @out 
WHERE TicketType = @TicketType

SET @TicketID = (SELECT TicketID FROM @out)
```

Since the UPDATE is atomic, it serializes the updates and everyone gets a unique TicketID.

I've tested it by having 2 processes, each in a loop, hitting it 10,000 times each with no delays in the loop. I saved the generated TicketID's to a table and then verified there were no duplicates.

Comment: Don't calculate your own PK. Use an identity or a Sequential GUID which are both built in to the engine. Also you should wrap execution of code in transactions so inserts happen sequentially.

Comment: Do not calculate your own primary key. Additionally, restrict the scope of generated sequences by using transactions.

Comment: I'd maintain the sequence values in a separate table with a key of TicketType and update the value in a transaction to avoid the race condition you ran into.

Comment: @DanGuzman this is what I ended up doing. See my solution above.

Comment: Tip: `GetDate()` is treated a bit oddly in queries. Each _instance_ will have a constant value within a query. For example `select GetDate() as D1, GetDate() as D2 from SomeTable` may return two different values for the two columns, but they will not vary from one row to the next. When using multiple calls to `GetDate()`, whether in a single statement or multiple statements, one may avoid interesting surprises by getting a single value and using it throughout, i.e. `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();` and use `@Now` as needed. Your original code called `GetDate()` at least thrice.

Comment: The original code was written over a year ago when I was new at this. You'll notice my new code does exactly what you advised.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't avoid using an identity or GUID, you can use a custom sequence which will handle the race condition you encountered. SQL Server will handle the hard part of dishing out the next number in the sequence and by using the `cycle` argument it will wrap around and start back at the `minvalue` when the last number `maxvalue` is used.

```
create sequence dbo.TicketNumber as smallint
start with 1
increment by 1
minvalue 1
maxvalue 9999
cycle;

-- This will give you the next value in line each time it's run
select next value for dbo.TicketNumber as TicketNumber
```

I would suggest that you don't store the TicketType, date, and incrementing number all in one field. It would be better if you had a column for each value and had your primary key be all 3 columns, e.g.:

```
create table dbo.tblTickets
(
    TicketType char(4) not null,
    TicketDate char(6) not null,
    TicketNumber smallint not null,
    constraint PK_TicketType_TicketDate_TicketNumber primary key
    (
        TicketType,
        TicketDate,
        TicketNumber
    )
)
```

Comment: This is intriguing but I don't think it will work for my use case. I need to reset the sequence for each Ticket Type to 1 on a new date.  Also, each Ticket Type has to have its own sequence. I believe I've come up with something that works. I'll add it to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a case where you will insert more than 9999 tickets in a day, what you have will work fine until 100 years after you started inputting values, then the 2 digit year will get you.

**The transaction wrapping is the only change you need to implement to prevent the case you bumped into.**

While others will disagree, making your primary key this way is fine, it fits your use case, you know its limitations, and it is more meaningful in your business case than a random guid.

Using the built in guid, or integer identity, would have stopped the error you had from occuring, but if your current key of type-date-number has any business value you would lose that, or still have to maintain that constraint while also maintaining the guid.